# What do these ports mean? Why are they open?

Tags: networking, security, nmap

running nmap on localhost, i get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysIuq.png

```
C:\Users\user>nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-10-24 07:26 India Standard Time
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00038s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
135/tcp  open  msrpc
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
2179/tcp open  vmrdp
```

the ports 134, 445 and 2179 are open.
Is this a vulnerability? Is it necessary to close them?
What should I do?
Doing a google search, i get:

```
msrpc is "Microsoft Remote Procedure Call Service"
vmrdp is used to connect to virtual machines
445 is used by SMB (Server Message Block). SMB is a network protocol used mainly in Windows networks for sharing ressources (e.g. files or printers) over a network. It can also be used to remotely execute commands.
```

If I remember correctly, I use virtual machines now and then, but I don't understand why its open when i'm not using it currently. Also, I don't understand why the others are open too? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: None of these is a vulnerablity. These ports are opened by background processes of windows and it doesn't necessarily means they are accessing the internet. As for vmrdp, both VirtualBox and VMware installs drivers on your system, for achieving certain things, and I suppose this is your network driver, so this is not a threat either

Comment: @saaranshgarg thanks of clearing the confusion